# Office365 API Service Level Accounts

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, exchangewebservices, office365

I was wondering if the Office365 API supports service level accounts yet. By service level, I mean that a single "service user" (an application for example), can authenticate itself over OAuth2 against our O365 account and access all of our users mail, calendars and files on their behalf.

We're aware that you can do this using EWS (which we have been doing), but we really want to get using O365 REST.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but we're working on it. Follow me on Twitter (@JasonJohMSFT) or watch our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/) for the announcement.